# How do I link libzmq on Windows?

Tags: windows, linker, rust, rust-cargo

I want to link libzmq with my Rust program. I have this in `~\.cargo\config`:

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.chainsaw]
rustc-link-search = ["C:\\Program Files\\ZeroMQ 4.0.4\\bin"]
```

Running `cargo test` results in this error:

```
   Compiling chainsaw v0.0.1 (file:///D:/chainsaw)
error: linking with `gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "gcc" "-Wl,--enable-long-section-names" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-nostdlib" "-m64" "C:\\Rust
\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\crt2.o" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "-L"
 "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "D:\\chainsaw\\target\\debug\\deps\\chainsaw-0154e16e13da8295.0.o"
 "-o" "D:\\chainsaw\\target\\debug\\deps\\chainsaw-0154e16e13da8295.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "D:\\
chainsaw\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-Wl,-Bdynamic"
"-l" "zmq" "D:\\chainsaw\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibc-29ef97a68464c2b7.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows
-gnu\\lib\\libtest-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libterm-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\
\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgetopts-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib
\\libstd-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\l
ib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\l
ibrand-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcollections-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\
\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_unicode-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\li
b\\liblibc-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\r
ustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc_system-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\
libcore-f5a209a9.rlib" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-f5a209a9.rlib" "-l" "ke
rnel32" "-l" "ws2_32" "-l" "userenv" "-l" "shell32" "-l" "advapi32" "-l" "gcc_eh" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsv
crt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "C:\\Rust\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: ld: cannot find -lzmq
```

As you can see, `-L "C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 4.0.4\bin"` is not being passed to the linker.

Why does setting `rustc-link-search` in the Cargo config file not work?

I have already checked these things:

- Cargo actually reads the config file
- The directory exists
- `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` is my target triple
- "chainsaw" is the name of my target
- The same error occurs when doing a clean build

Comment: Is the ZeroMq compiled for gnu abi?

Comment: Why are you using `[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.chainsaw]`? Where did you learn about that syntax? The [Cargo docs don't mention it](http://doc.crates.io/config.html), they only go so far as the triple.